# Google Analytics - Track events in an Iframe without access to parent code

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to track different events (pageviews and clicks) inside an Iframe we have built inside a portal.

- We do not have access to the parent sites code
- The Iframe and parent site have different domains

Is it possible to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: If both parent and iframe have same domain, it is possible. If they are on different domains, no, it is not possible. If your situation is the former, then make your question more specific.

Comment: @CrayonViolent The domains are completely different because the portal is hosted by a 3rd party.

Comment: Yeah sorry, can't access then. Check out [Same Domain Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) for details why.

Answer (score 0):

You can add tracking codes on pages in iframe and track what you need inside iframe.

Comment: I have the tracking codes and tags set up in the iframe, but none of it gets recorded in Google Analytics.

Comment: @RyanNisbet It is strange. I've tracked iframes many times. Try to check implementation.